# Redirect to Docker container with Apache in a relative URL

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, docker, url

I have a Docker container running on a Ubuntu server on the port 8080. I can access to the web container with localhost:8080

Now I want to access to this container from the outside with my public IP on a relative URL. For example: 19x.xx.xx.xx/gitlab

I created a proxy reversed in Apache but I only can load the main page, without css, js or other resources like the links from inside the web, because they are the same so I can't access them from outside.

```
ProxyPass        /gitlab/ http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab/ http://localhost:8080
```

Is there any way for mapping all the resources from the page and redirect it using Apache with a relative URL?